# Android Glide does not resize image

Tags: android-glide, image-resizing

I try to resize an image (of which size was defined in xml layout) using Glide library in Android. But the image does not resize. What can be the problem?

In xml:

```
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/folder_img"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp" android:layout_marginRight="18dp" android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"  android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/cat_pomelo_head"/>
```

In Java:

```
   Glide.with(mContext)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(snFolder.getImgUrl())
            .apply(new RequestOptions().override(34, 34))
            .into(itemViewHolder.folderImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours *folderImg CircleImageView's Visibility* is set to *GONE*

Set it to **android:visibility = "visible"**

Comment: I need to make it GONE.  I cannot set it to visible for layout  purpose.